# What exactly is an HTTP Entity?

Tags: http, httpclient

Would someone please describe to me what exactly an **HTTP entity** is?

I am reading the HTTPClient documentation, but I do not really understand what that means?

Comment: I came here from this write up on HTTP: [HTTP: The Protocol Every Web Developer Must Know](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-1/) if anyone else comes through here looking for information on the subject.

Comment: Note that the term "HTTP entity" no longer appears in the [latest HTTP 1.1 specifications](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230).  Looks like it's been deprecated.  Now we can just use "header fields" and "message body".

Answer (score 152, accepted):

An [HTTP entity](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html) is the majority of an HTTP request or response, consisting of [some of the headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.1) and the body, if present.  It seems to be the entire request or response without the request or status line (although only [certain header fields are considered part of the entity](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.1)).

To illustrate; here's a request:

```text
POST /foo HTTP/1.1          # Not part of the entity.
Content-Type: text/plain    # ┬ The entity is from this line down...
Content-Length: 1234        # │
                            # │
Hello, World! ...           # ┘
```

And a response:

```text
HTTP/1.1 200 OK             # Not part of the entity.
Content-Length: 438         # ┬ The entity is from this line down...
Content-Type: text/plain    # │
                            # │
Response body ...           # ┘
```

Comment: *Host* is not an entity header field.

Comment: I thought an entity was using `&amp;` instead of `&`. Isn't that an entity too? What's the difference?

Comment: @Imray: `&amp;` is an [*HTML* character entity reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), not the same an an *HTTP Entity*.

Comment: @maerics Can you describe the difference?

Comment: @Imray: that's a separate question, not a good fit for a comment to this thread.

Comment: @lmray: they are entirely different entities. ;) (One is about *encoding* strings in a _HTML text_, the other is about *structuring* information when a browser and a server talk to each other over the _HTTP protocol_. Also, one is more confusing than the other. Or vice versa. ;-o )

Comment: Note that the term "HTTP entity" no longer appears in the [latest HTTP 1.1 specifications](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230).  Looks like it's been deprecated.  Now we can just stick with "header fields" and "message body".

Answer (score 20):

Here are 3 simple cases:

Case 1. You're uploading 3 files in a single request. Those 3 files are 3 entities. Each of them has its own `Content-Type` to indicate what kind of file it is.

Case 2. You're viewing a web page. Browser has downloaded an html file as entity in the background. Since the page could be updated continuously, you may get a totally different entity later.

Case 3. You've got a `304 Not Modified`. No entity has been transferred.

In a word, **Entity is an optional payload inside an http message**(either request or response), so it is a "**part-whole**" relation between Entity and Message.

Some header fields apply to `Message` like `Transfer-Encoding` describe how to transfer message between intermediaries, and thus MAY be added or removed by any application along the request/response chain(`hop-by-hop headers`). In comparison, those header fields apply to `Entity` are some properties, which describe entity's size, type, compression algorithm, etc...

Further reading, quoting from RFC 2616 section 1.4, 4.5 and 4.3:

- A request/response chain

> ```
>      request chain -------------------------------------->
>    UA -----v----- A -----v----- B -----v----- C -----v----- O
>       <------------------------------------- response chain
> ```
>
> The figure above shows three intermediaries (A, B, and C) between the user agent and origin server. A request or response message that travels the whole chain will pass through four separate connections.

- Header fields either for Message or Entity

> There are a few header fields which have general applicability for both request and response messages, but which do not apply to **the entity being transferred**. These header fields apply only to **the message being transmitted**.

- Header fields for Message could be changed along the chain

> Transfer-Encoding MUST be used to indicate any transfer-codings applied by an application to ensure safe and proper transfer of the message. **Transfer-Encoding is a property of the message, not of the entity, and thus MAY be added or removed by any application along the request/response chain.**

- Relation between message body and entity body

`message-body = Transfer-Encoding( Content-Encoding(entity-body) )`

where `Transfer-Encoding` may be "chunked" which means how to transfer the message, and `Content-Encoding` may be "gzip" that stands for how to compress the entity.

Comment: Wow, thanks for clarifying the "part-whole" relation between entity and message! The rest kinda' adds to the confusion, but overall, still worth an upvote. Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

It is an **abstraction representing** a request or response **payload**. The [JavaDoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) is clear on its purpose and various entity types.

Comment: +1 for calling it "payload", which finally adds some meaning to that void term ("entity").

Answer (score 7):

I guess the HTTPClient [`Entity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html) is named according to HTTP [Entity](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html).

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is a Protocol which is observed when accessing information from a remote machine through a network. Usually the network is internet and the remote machine is a server.

When you ask for information from person A to person B, you give him a message. (Request). Person B replies to you (Response). Request and Response are HTTP Message Types.

Person A can ask Person B to do something, instead of asking for information. Say, Person A wants Person B to store a file in a secure location. So, Person A passes that file(HTTP Entity) to Person B and ask him to do something(HTTP Message). In this case, Person is passing an "Entity". In the context of HTTP Entity, it is a payload attached with the message.

Hope the analogy helped.

Answer (score 2):

As said in a comment by @hawkeye-parker, it looks like Entity has been deprecated. Make a [search in this 2014 rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), and you will see about XML entities and message body, but nothing about Http entity.

Nevertheless, HttpClient, but also JaxRS client, have a `setEntity()` and `getEntity()` method.

Considering the accepted answer, both libraries are wrong ! `HttpClient.setEntity()` won't remove previously set headers.

Comment: I found the distinction of "Entity" (and related "entity-headers")  and "Message" quite useful. This becomes quickly apparent, when you design a network library, and perform an analysis of an HTTP message and its various incarnations, e.g. a multipart message. Unfortunately, the new RFCs merges these distinct "classes" into one and we need to introduce our own terminology, or stick with "Entity".

Answer (score 2):

`HttpEntity` is what you are going to pass in Request(with header) and what you are getting in Response.
For Get Request we are passing simple String

```java
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
 HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
```

For Post We are going to pass complete Entity Class

```java
public String createProducts(@RequestBody Product product) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<Product> entity = new HttpEntity<Product>(product,headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(
             "http://localhost:8080/products", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class
           ).getBody();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Among the good answers that we have here, I believe that is worth to mention something that comes directly from the [RFC 2616 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol - HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-42):

> **Entity**
>
> Request and Response messages MAY transfer an entity if not otherwise
> restricted by the request method or response status code. **An entity
> consists** of entity-header fields and an entity-body, although some
> responses will only include the entity-headers.

**In a a nutshell:** an Entity may be transferred, and it can be the *header* + *body*, or just the *header*.

Since that there's the link above, I detain myself on making additional comments.

Answer (score 0):

Entity is something like a message, it consists of header, where are metadata such as location,lang,encoding ...

And optionally of a body - it content is formated etc as specified in header

Answer (score 0):

Latest HTTP 1.1 RFC 7230 has used term Payload instead of Entity. Some old documentation still keep referring the old terminology.

Important practical thing to remember about Entity(Payload) is:

If Transfer-Encoding doesn't exist, Message Body = Entity(Payload) Body.

If Transfer-Encoding exists, Entity(Payload) Body has to be obtained by applying proper decoding and extracting.