# Confusion about entities as used in the HTTP Specification

Tags: http, web, http-headers, webserver

I'm reading the HTTP spec, and I can't figure out exactly what "entities" are. I read the answer to "[What exactly is an HTTP Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197745/what-is-excactly-an-http-entity)", but I'm still confused.

Specifically, I don't understand the distinction the spec makes between entity-headers and response/request/general-headers. For example, reading the [Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14) section, headers such as `Allow`, `Expires`, and `Last-Modified` are classified as "entity-headers." What does that actually mean? I guess they apply to an "entity-body", but what's the difference between an entity-body and a message-body?

I'd appreciate any clarification on entities and where they fit in a HTTP request/response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *message* is the most generic term and refers to a whole [HTTP message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4), including the *start-line*, *message-header* fields, and the *message-body* (may be empty).

The [*entity*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7) of a message is the payload that is to be transmitted. This can be identical to the *message-body*, but if there was a transfer encoding applied to the *entity*, the [*entity-body*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2) is obtained from the *message-body* by decoding any transfer encodings.

An example for such a transfer encoding is the [*chunked* transfer coding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) where the entity body is transferred in chunks, e.g.:

```
HTTP/1.0 OK 200
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

9
This is a
C
 chunked mess
4
age.
0
‍
```

Here the *message-body* is:

```
9
This is a
C
 chunked mess
4
age.
0
‍
```

but the *entity-body* is the *message-body* with decoded *chunked* encoding:

```
This is a chunked message.
```

Comment: I see, that makes more sense! So would the "message-header" contain all four header distinctions (entity, request, response, and generic headers?) And then would the answer to the previous question I posted be incorrect? He says everything except for the response/request line  is part of the entity, even though the `Host` header isn't an "entity-header".

Comment: @theabraham Again, *message-header* is the generic term. And any header is a *message-header*. For requests and responses, there are special [request header fields](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.3) and [response header fields](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-6.2). Header fields, that can be used in both requests and responses are [general header fields](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.5). And header fields that specifically describe the entity are [entity header fields](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-7.1).

Comment: Very cool, thank you. That's what I thought, but the previous answer to a similar question (which I saw you commented on) put everything as an entity. That led to some confusion.

Comment: @theabraham And, yes, as I’ve already commented on the other answer, *Host* is not an [entity header field](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-7.1) as it doesn’t describe the entity. It rather describes the destination the entity is to be sent to.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1. You're uploading 3 files in a http request. Those 3 files are 3 entities. Each of them  has its own `Content-Type` to indicate what kind of file it is.

Case 2. You're viewing a web page. Browser has downloaded a html file as the entity via a http response in the background. The file may be updated continuously. So the entity you got yesterday may be different from the one you get today.

Case 3. You've got a `304 Not Modified`. No entity has been transmitted.

An entity is an optional payload inside a http request or response. Part of the headers are used to describe it.